# Recursively compile seperate .cpp files Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

I have a file structure like this:

```
Project
|-- program1
|   `-- main.cpp
|-- program2
|   `-- main.cpp
`-- program3
    `-- main.cpp
```

I would like to create a makefile, at the project root, that automatically gets all the .cpp files recursively and compiles them to a file in the same folder. Like this:

```
Project
|-- program1
|   |-- main.cpp
|   `-- main.o
|-- program2
|   |-- main.cpp
|   `-- main.o
`-- program3
    |-- main.cpp
    `-- main.o
```

These programs have nothing to do with each other, so there isn't any overlap.

I have never created a makefile before and the documentation is very hard to follow. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you *seem* to be asking for (if you're using GNU make):

```
SRCS := $(wildcard */*.cpp)
OBJS := $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SRCS))

all: $(OBJS)
```

Your question is somewhat confusing because your example only shows compiling source files into object files, but the name of the directories says "program".

Please make your question more clear and detailed, if the above isn't what you want.